# Websphere 6.1 Ldap Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, websphere

I have recently upgraded from websphere 5.1.2 to websphere 6.1 server. I had some ldap code to query active direcotry that worked fine on 5.1.2 but now does not work on 6.1.

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Mode: SSL not implemented
```

Is this because the security IBM is using is not compatible with ActiveDirectory? If not is there a way to force it to use the previous security stream so I can continue to make these calls?

-- EDIT -- 
I have tried to add the sun JSSE jars to the path of the application server and the deployed probject. Also I updated the security policy to include sun's implementation. This still doesn't work..Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid and was using old version of jsse.jars. I copied them from my jdk1.5 install to the websphere/lib/ext directory and it seems to be working now.